# Send push notification via notification hub to all users

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

I've been trying to figure out for a long time how to send a push notification in my asp.net web api. I saw that there are to ways to register a device in the hub, through the device itself and through the backend. I want to use the first method, and found some tutorial that does it, but I don't know how to send the request from the backend. I tried the following code, but it gives me 401 Unauthorized error:

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> NotTry()
    {
        NotificationOutcome outcome;
        HttpStatusCode ret = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        string notif = "{ \"data\" : {\"message\":\"hello\"}}";
        outcome = await Notifications.Instance.Hub.SendGcmNativeNotificationAsync(notif);
        if (outcome != null)
        {
            if (!((outcome.State == NotificationOutcomeState.Abandoned) ||
                (outcome.State == NotificationOutcomeState.Unknown)))
            {
                ret = HttpStatusCode.OK;
            }
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(ret);
    }
```

If anyone could give me a direction, I'll be grateful. I am loosing my mind searching for a solution...

Answer (score 1):

> but I don't know how to send the request from the backend. I tried the following code, but it gives me 401 Unauthorized error

According to your description, you are using the 
[Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs) for Microsoft Azure Notification Hubs back end operations.

```
NotificationHubClient Hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString("<your hub's DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature>","<hub name>"); 
await hub.SendGcmNativeNotificationAsync("{payload}");
```

I would recommend you check the notification Hub Connection when constructing the `NotificationHubClient` via the method `CreateClientFromConnectionString`, and make sure the connection string has the correct full access. You could just create a console application using the above nuget package to send the notification and use the fiddler to capture the detailed error response to narrow down this issue. Moreover, you could follow [Diagnose dropped notifications in Notification Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-fixer).

Comment: I can swear I didn't change anything, I just deleted the connection strings (which I'm sure were correct) and re-entered them, and magically it worked. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Glad to hear that you have solved this issue. For 401, it means that your  credential is incorrect, and the `DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature` policy is generated by default. Maybe your previous connection string has other invalid character(s).